# InDesign CS3 package script

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs3

Wanted to find a way to get this script, but after I Google'd this, it seems that it's not so easy to find. Can anyone help me with this? I need a script that makes a folder with job name and in the folder creates `.indd`, `.inx`, `.pdf` files that links and embeds fonts.

Comment: I'm confused. Indesign cs3 has this under `File > Package...`

Comment: Of course I know that it is under there :)) but I was asking for script...

Comment: @The1stLeo can you be a little clearer as to why what Joonas has mentioned doesn't work?  Because at this time I too do not understand what your question needs and I would also suggest `File > Package`.  Are you asking for a way to output everything such as `.indd`, `.pdf`, fonts resources etc. etc. in a package folder?

Comment: Yes. I need to find a way to make a package folder with .indd, .pdf, .inx, fonts and links, NOT doing it manually with File->Package or Shift+Alt+Cmd+P BUT like run a script to run this process.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about design, it's about scripting specifically. As such it should really be on SO or perhaps SU.

Answer (score 0):

InDesign CS3 JS API exposes Document object method:

```
bool packageForPrint (to: File,
    copyingFonts: bool,
    copyingLinkedGraphics: bool,
    copyingProfiles: bool,
    updatingGraphics: bool,
    includingHiddenLayers: bool,
    ignorePreflightErrors: bool,
    creatingReport: bool
    [, versionComments: string]
    [, forceSave: bool=false])
```

This is programatically equivalent to the <kbd>Package</kbd> action. The same object also has method

```
void exportFile (format: varies,
    to: File
    [, showingOptions: bool=false]
    [, using: PDFExportPreset]
    [, versionComments: string]
    [, forceSave: bool=false])
```

which can be used to produce PDF, INX and other supported files types.

You'll find more information at http://jongware.mit.edu/indesigncs3jshelp/pc_Document.html and in appropriate *InDesign Scripting Guide*.